# Where does Ubuntu Tweak save the wallpaper?

Tags: directory, ubuntu-tweak

I guess the title says it all.

I would like to save the pictures to my external drive to use it on my other OS.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't appear to cache any images. It saves the current background at `/home/<username>/.config/ubuntu-tweak/lovewallpaper.jpg`

I gathered this info using `lsof` - it only saves the files it downloads in a temporary directory while downloading, then deletes it and replaces the current one with the next one.

Gather the backgrounds you want and copy that picture for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use this tool so I can't really say, but if I should make a guess I'd say have a look at /usr/share/backgrounds/.

Comment: No they aren't there.

Comment: Ubuntu tweak doesn't have root privileges. If it was going to store it into something like that, it would store them at `/home/<user>/.local/share/backgrounds`. `/home/<user>/.local/share` is the user's equivalent to `/usr/local/share`.